# UML: final state

Tags: uml

Let's assume we have the following state diagram (from UML reference book) which describes states of some object:
[image]

If object now is in state `Y` and `e` event is triggered will the object come in state `Z` after coming to final state, assuming that after `e` event there are NO more events? I am asking as for me it is not quite clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citing Superstructures for 2.5 (FinalState):

> **14.5.2.1 Description**
>
> A special kind of State, which, when entered, signifies that the enclosing Region has completed. If the enclosing Region is directly contained in a StateMachine and all other Regions in that StateMachine also are completed, then it means that the entire StateMachine behavior is completed.

That means in your concrete case: when `e` happens the  state `X` is finalized and transfers unconditionally to `z`.